# Get category thumbnail NULL

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

im having trouble getting the category thumbnails from the store, in the admin panel it shows the category thubmnail added on the category.

But when i try to show in the frontend, is giving me null Dont understand why.

```
$category =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', Mage::registry('current_category')->getId());

?>

<ul class="catblocks">

    <?php
 foreach ($category as $cat){
            $entity_id = $cat->getId();
            $name = $cat->getName();
            $url_key = $cat->getUrlKey();
            $url_path = $cat->getUrlPath();
            $skin_url = $cat->getThumbnail(); 


     echo '<li>
        <a href="'.$url_path.'">
            <img src="https://shopping.pt/media/catalog/category/'.$skin_url.'"alt="'.$name.'">
            <span>'.$name.'</span>
        </a>
    </li>';
    } 

    ?>


</ul>
```

Comment: why you print `$cat["magic_thumbnail"]`?

Comment: Sorry, is wrong, dont botther with this..

Comment: Try img src = `Mage::getBaseUrl('media').'catalog/category/'.$cat->getThumbnail()` instead of static

Comment: the $cat->getThumb‌​nail() is giving me null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will have to load the collection

```
$category =  Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                            ->addAttributeToFilter('parent_id', Mage::registry('current_category')->getId())
                            ->load();
```